# array_pop to remove object within a array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class from which I am getting array

```
$attributeTypeOfProducts= $Attributetypes::with('cars')->get();
```

I want to remove the last record of the array by using array_pop method but it gives following error

```
Indirect modification of overloaded element of App\\Models\\Attributetypes has no effect
```

I did following

```
$pc=0;
$popcount =0;
for( $i = 0; $i < count($attributeTypeOfProducts); $i++){ 

 for($pc=0; $pc<5; $pc++)
             {
                 
               
                array_pop($attributeTypeOfProducts[$i]['cars']);
               
             }



}


                    Response of the class

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "cars",
    "car_id": 123443221,
    "status": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-08-02T05:53:49.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-08-02T05:53:49.000000Z",
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "attr_size_value": 14,
            "attr_image_src": "abc.png",
            "attribute_size_name": "honda",
            "attribute_type_id": 1,
            "product_id": 123443221,
            "created_at": "2021-08-02T05:53:50.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-02T05:53:50.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "attr_size_value": 10,
            "attr_image_src": "abc.png",
            "attribute_size_name": "bullet",
            "attribute_type_id": 2,
            "product_id": 123443221,
            "created_at": "2021-08-02T05:54:28.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-02T05:54:28.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "attr_size_value": 12,
            "attr_image_src": "abc.png",
            "attribute_size_name": "hyundai",
            "attribute_type_id": 3,
            "product_id": 123443221,
            "created_at": "2021-08-02T05:55:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-02T05:55:02.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "attr_size_value": 14,
            "attr_image_src": "abc.png",
            "attribute_size_name": "city",
            "attribute_type_id": 3,
            "product_id": 123443221,
            "created_at": "2021-08-02T05:55:02.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-08-02T05:55:02.000000Z"
        }
    ],
    
}
```

I want to remove the record with attribute_size_name = city But it crashes on array_pop

I have cars relation of which i want to remove the last record but it gives the mentioned error

After doing this
$attributeTypeOfProducts= $Attributetypes::with('cars')->get()->toArray();
I am unable to push my other array in to the $attributeTypeOfProducts

Comment: The get() method returns a collection, not an array.  Look at the documentation for collections, it will make adding/removing items easier. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your result using converting collection to array using `toArray()` method:

```
$attributeTypeOfProducts= $Attributetypes::with('cars')->get()->toArray();
```

You can also done this using methods in laravel collection:

```
$attributeTypeOfProducts= $Attributetypes::with('cars')->get();

$attributeTypeOfProducts->map(function($item, $key){
    if($key < 5){
        array_pop($item['cars']);
        return $item;
    }
})
```

Comment: Why would you convert the collection to an array?

Comment: @GertB. Because I wanted to save his solution (working with arrays). I will add an extra solution for working with collections.

Comment: I would even use the collections functions instead of mapping.  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-slice

Comment: @GertB. and after slicing how would you merge it with the remaining items of the collection?